# Questions in algebraic geometry related to finding $V_A(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is from Algebraic Geometry assignment and I was unable to solve some of these:

> (a) I have solved.

(b) Prove that the polynomial $X^3 +X^2 +X+1 \in \mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{Z}4[X]$ is a multiple of $X+1$ and $X+3$ but not of $(X+1) (X+3)$.

I proved that it is a multiple of $X+1$ and $X+3$ by showing that $X^3+X^2 +X+1$ has  both $-1$ and $-3$ as a root but I am unable to understand why it cannot have both as root simultaneously.

(c) Give an example of a commutative ring $A$ such that $V_A (X^2 -X) $ is infinite.

I am unable to find such a ring. There must be infinite number of elements satisfying $X^2=X$. So, ring must be infinite. examples are : $\mathbb{Z}$ , $\mathbb{Q}$ but they don't satisfy the given condition. So, please help.

(d) and (e) I have done.

Kindly help.

Comment: What do you call $V_A(\cdot)$ ?

Comment: @charmd Solutions(roots) of equation . in $ A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first two questions, simply note that \begin{align*} P(X)=X^3+X^2+X+1 & = (X+1)(X^2+1) \\ & = (X+3)(X^2 + 2X + 3) \\ & = (X+1)(X+3)\cdot (X+1) + 2X+2\end{align*}

The remainder is zero in the first two cases, not in the third one.

For your question (c), a ring like $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}}$ fits the bill: every single element $x$ inside it is such that $x^2=x$ (and it is infinite).

Comment: How did you wrote $(X+1)(X^2+1) $  equal to $(X+3)(X^2 + 2X + 3)$ in (b). Can you explain?

Comment: When you expand $(X+3)(X^2+2X+1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, you get $X^3+5X^2+9X+9$. Expand it in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}[X]$ instead and you get $X^3+X^2+X+1$. To clarify, there is no obvious link between $(X+1)(X^2+1)$ and $(X+3)(X^2+2X+3)$: each time expand to find the original expanded polynomial